# Expression of probability

Tags: probability, self-study

Given the following question...

[image]

I'm still unclear why it's

$$P(T|L)$$

and not

$$P(L|T)$$

[image]

Appreciate any advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the difficulty lies. You should probably clarify why you think what you do.

$P(T|L)$ is "Probability test yields oil given low reserve"

The questions states "if an area has a small oil reserve then the probability that the test drills will yield oil is 0.2"

The first part specifies the *condition* (an area has a small oil reserve) ($L$)

The second part specifies the probability of the outcome. (Probability of $T$)

So when the condition ($L$) holds, $P(T)$ is $0.2$. You write that as $P(T|L)=0.2$.